# System.DirectoryServices.Protocol move user question

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to move a user from one OU to a Different OU, and also to update a few attributes using System.DirectoryServices.Protocol, but I'm having a very hard time finding any code samples for anything except searching.

Can anyone please post some code samples and or links to code samples/tutorials for these two operation in S.DS.P?

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to the article called [Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx) inside you'll find a shortcut to download [MS_Sample_Pack_For_SDSP.EXE](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18086) which is a solution with many examples :

```
MoveRenameObject server_or_domain_name originalDn newParentDn objectName
```

may be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example from a very good source of c# Active Directory examples at [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#23%20Howto%3a%20%28Almost%29%20Everything%20In%20Active%20Directory%20via%20C#)

```
//Move an object from one ou to another
DirectoryEntry eLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + objectLocation);
DirectoryEntry nLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + newLocation);
string newName = eLocation.Name;
eLocation.MoveTo(nLocation, newName);
nLocation.Close();
eLocation.Close();

//Modify an attribute of a user object

DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
int val = (int)user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val & ~0x2; 
user.CommitChanges();
user.Close();
```

Comment: Yep that's a great Reference if you're using System.DirectoryServices, but not if you are using System.DirectoryServices.Protocol. S.DS = easier, S.DS.P = faster Alas I'm using S.DS.P...