# System.DirectoryServices.Protocol add/remove user from group

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I want to Add remove a user from a group in System.DirectoryServices.Protocol namespace.

I have the samples mentioned here :

[link to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353769/system-directoryservices-protocol-move-user-question)

But can't find an exampel fo how to add and remove a user from a group using S.DS.P.

Does anyone know of any samples for this operation?

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: and in what exactly the examples given to you did not help: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18086 ??

Comment: I looked through it and didn't see any samples involving groups. Did i just miss it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those who follow, here is how I actually solved the problem using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

```
string adServer = "";
            string adServerUser = "";
            string adServerPassword = "";
            string adServerContainer = "";

            GetSettings( ref adServer, ref adServerUser, ref adServerPassword, ref adServerContainer );

            if ( ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServer) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerUser)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerPassword)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerContainer))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adServer, adServerContainer, adServerUser, adServerPassword))
                    {
                        using (GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, this.textBox_GroupAdd.Text))
                        {
                            if (group == null)
                            {
                                FlexibleMessageBox.Show("group could not be found");
                                return;
                            }
                            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> x = group.GetMembers();
                            using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, this.textBox_adName.Text))
                            {
                                string userSid = string.Format("<SID={0}>", ToSidString(user));
                                DirectoryEntry groupDirectoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry) group.GetUnderlyingObject();
                                groupDirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userSid);
                                groupDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    FlexibleMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                FlexibleMessageBox.Show("group add done");
            }
```

and here is the guts of the remove from group

```
                    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, this.textBox_adName.Text))
                    {
                        string userSid = string.Format("<SID={0}>", ToSidString(user));
                        DirectoryEntry groupDirectoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry) group.GetUnderlyingObject();
                        groupDirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].Remove(userSid);
                        groupDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
                    }
```

Comment: The question was specifically for `System.DirectoryServices.Protocol`, and I only say this because for me in a linux Azure App Service Plan only Protocol works. Not AccountManagement or any other library I have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You'd just want to send a `ModifyRequest` on the `member` attribute with a `DirectoryAttributeOperation.Add`. The value you should pass is the DN of the user you want to add to the group

Answer (score 1):

Here a example to add a object to a group.

```
    public static void AddObjectToGroup(string objectName, string groupName)
    {
        // var credential = new NetworkCredential();
        // var identifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("");
        using (var connection = new LdapConnection("company.com"))
        {
            connection.SessionOptions.StartTransportLayerSecurity(null);
            connection.Bind();

            string objectDn = null;
            var request = new SearchRequest("DC=company,DC=com", $"Name={objectName}", SearchScope.Subtree, "distinguishedName");
            var response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
            if (response != null)
            {
                var enumerator = response.Entries.GetEnumerator();
                enumerator.Reset();
                if (enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator.Current is SearchResultEntry entry)
                {
                    objectDn = entry.Attributes["distinguishedName"].GetValues(typeof(string)).Select(x => (string)x).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            Log.Information($"object DN: {objectDn}");

            string groupDn = null;
            request = new SearchRequest("DC=company,DC=com", $"Name={groupName}", SearchScope.Subtree, "distinguishedName"); 
            response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
            if (response != null)
            {
                var enumerator = response.Entries.GetEnumerator();
                enumerator.Reset();
                if (enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator.Current is SearchResultEntry entry)
                {
                    groupDn = entry.Attributes["distinguishedName"].GetValues(typeof(string)).Select(x => (string)x).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            Log.Information($"group DN: {groupDn}");

            request = new SearchRequest("DC=company,DC=com", $"(&(objectCategory=Group)(distinguishedName={groupDn}))", SearchScope.Subtree);
            response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
            if (response != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objectDn))
            {
                var members = response.Entries[0].Attributes["member"];

                var existing = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < members.Count; i++)
                {
                    existing.Add(members[i].ToString());
                }

                if (existing.Contains(objectDn)) return;
                
                var dam = new DirectoryAttributeModification { Name = "member" };
                dam.Add(objectDn);
                dam.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Add;

                var mr = new ModifyRequest(groupDn, dam);
                var dr = connection.SendRequest(mr);
                Log.Information($"Add Response: {dr.ResultCode.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }
```